# Jenkins + Docker + Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am currently running `Jenkins 2.89.3` with `Docker 17.12.0-ce-win47` on Windows 10, with Linux containers.

I am trying to run the following Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker 'maven:3.3.3' }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error in Jenkins:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'maven:3.3.3'. Error: docker:
Error response from daemon: the working directory
'C:\Users\c.c\.jenkins\workspace\Neo4jTime_master-R4QSBCTASBURK2MQKHAPXGLIBNT65CJORPZCYLPCGRG75IGOQKTA'
is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Docker plugin automatically mounts the workspace folder into the container using '-v' argument (you can see this in the log of the build). This is probably the cause for the error

Comment: Yes you are right. Still, is there some way I could make this work?

Comment: Don't run jenkins master on Windows. you better even run it as Docker container on Windows

Comment: At the moment, Jenkins Docker Pipeline plugin on the Windows host can't execute Linux Docker images due to a bug https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60473

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to install Jenkins on Windows. Example solution it to Run **Jenkins in Docker with Docker inside**.

I prepared small README how to set up Jenkins in Docker with Docker inside and with an example Jenkinsfile https://github.com/auriuki/jenkins-docker

In short: run Jenkins in Docker like it is in the official Jenkins documentation.

```
docker run ^
  -u root ^
  --rm ^
  -d ^
  -p 8080:8080 ^
  -p 50000:50000 ^
  -v "E:/Docker/Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home ^
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
  --name jenkins ^
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

where `E:/Docker/Jenkins` is a created directory for jenkins configuration, workspec, etc. - to avoid loosing data after container is removed.

Comment: Good point. I didn't want to copy paste whole instruction, but you are right. I will keep it in mind in the future. I added the general solution - how to run in docker.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

This will work only if Jenkins will be installed on a Linux machine.
It is caused because Docker plugin mounts the workspace into the container (using the -v argument) and a Windows-path doesn't exists in Linux.